# C#: How to parse the AVL data packets coming from the Device FM4100 get the output as hexadecimal value

Tags: c#, avl-tree

Is my parsing method worng?

I got like this avl data format: `08010013ba7695698059a9f580eb76a140280048b045021f0101c70005e`

```
Codec ID :08
Count:01
strTimeStamp:0013ba7695698
Longitude:59a9f580
Latitude :eb76a140
Altitude:280
Angle:048
Speed:045
```

I convert the data to decimal format . but my longitude and latitude were wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your time stamp seems to be missing some data (it must be 8 bytes).

Comment: -mhd yasseen  thanks for your reply .... i too refer the document .but the lenght of the packet always seem to be changed . so i split the avl data in the format of byte array..